# printing post table data in admin menu page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to retrieve data from post table into admin menu page. I have written my codes below. it doesn't display records from post table.

```
    function wdbp_menu_page(){
    add_menu_page( 
        __( 'My wpdb', 'wpdb' ),
        'my db',
        'manage_options',
        'customdb',
        'my_menu_page',
        7
    ); 
}
```

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wdbp_menu_page' );

```
function my_menu_page(){
global $wpdb;
$fivesdrafts = $wpdb->get_results(
    "
        SELECT *
        FROM $wpdb->posts
        WHERE post_status = 'draft'
        AND post_author = 5
    "
);
if ( $fivesdrafts ) {
    foreach ( $fivesdrafts as $post ) {
        setup_postdata( $post );
        ?>
        <h2>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permalink: <?php the_title(); ?>">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a>
        </h2>
        <?php
    }
} else {
echo "Page not fount";
```

}
}

Comment: Why use a custom SQL statement and not `WP_Query`? If you run your SQL statement directly on the database (using Terminal or a client) do you get results?

Comment: It works in theme's template page. But it doesn't work in admin pages.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend using `WP_Query` and getter functions (rather than print functions), so you don't have to use `setup_postdata()` (untested):

```php
function my_menu_page() {
    $fivesdrafts = new WP_Query( array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status'    => 'draft',
        'author'         => 5,
        'no_found_rows'  => true,
    ) );

    if ( ! $fivesdrafts->have_posts() ) {
        echo __( 'Page not found' );
    }

    foreach ( $fivesdrafts->posts as $post ) {
        $title = get_the_title( $post );

        printf( 
            '<h2><a href="%s" rel="bookmark" title="Permalink: %s">%s</a></h2>',
            esc_attr( get_permalink( $post ) ),
            esc_attr( $title ),
            esc_html( $title )
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

these codes work print mysql table datas into my admin menu page. thanks for
for your reply.

```
 function my_menu_page(){

global $wpdb;
$fivesdrafts = $wpdb->get_results(
    "
        SELECT *
        FROM slides
        WHERE ID = '1'
    "
);

$sql_results = $fivesdrafts;
if ($sql_results) {
    foreach ($sql_results as $post) {
      echo $post->name;
    }
}
```

}